# Concatenating Angular <Routes>array results in compile error

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

The application has standard routes which will be used by the customer and one for (UI) testing scoped modules (components) of the application. The developer must be able to use all the routes the customer has access to and additionally be able to acces the "dev-routes".

I've tried checking on the current environment and concatenating the two arrays (*of the same type*) into one array, this results in the compiler throwing an error:

```
webpack: Failed to compile.
webpack: Compiling...
Date: 2018-04-05T09:20:50.790Z - Hash: 4640ed7a42057bb6f11f - Time: 2046ms
6 unchanged chunks

ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

This is the error in the browser:

[image: Error log in inspector]

When the `.concat()` function is not used – simply by using only a ternary operator or by just having a dead simple routes variable – the routes do work as expected.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from '@app/environment';

const devRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dev',
        loadChildren: 'app/families/dev/dev.module#DevModule'
    },
];

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(environment.production ? routes : devRoutes.concat(routes))
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

**dev.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { DevRoutingModule } from './dev-routing.module';
import { DevHomeComponent } from './dev-home/dev-home.component';
import { DevTypographyComponent } from './dev-typography/dev-typography.component';
import { DevInputComponent } from './dev-input/dev-input.component';
import { DevExecuteComponent } from './dev-execute/dev-execute.component';
import { DevColorComponent } from './dev-color/dev-color.component';
import { DevVariablesComponent } from './dev-variables/dev-variables.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        DevRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        DevHomeComponent,
        DevTypographyComponent,
        DevInputComponent,
        DevExecuteComponent,
        DevColorComponent,
        DevVariablesComponent
    ]
})
export class DevModule {
}
```

**dev-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { DevHomeComponent } from './dev-home/dev-home.component';
import { DevTypographyComponent } from './dev-typography/dev-typography.component';
import { DevInputComponent } from './dev-input/dev-input.component';
import { DevExecuteComponent } from './dev-execute/dev-execute.component';
import { DevColorComponent } from './dev-color/dev-color.component';
import { DevVariablesComponent } from './dev-variables/dev-variables.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: DevHomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'typography',
        component: DevTypographyComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'input',
        component: DevInputComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'execute',
        component: DevExecuteComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'colors',
        component: DevColorComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'variables',
        component: DevVariablesComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DevRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: can you add the whole error message? Cause you don't do anything fancy here, and as you know it shoulds work

Comment: @PierreMallet I've included the whole log segment, it's a small error message with little to no content.

Comment: Ok see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7293 what you try to achieve with concat cant wok with angular-cli AOT

Answer (score 0):

Probably because is a ES6 const? Have you tried your `concat` on a let variable of devRoutes?

Comment: Yes, I've tried, this results in the same error being thrown.